# Converting from Cell References to Named Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel file that uses VBA code to hide/unhide rows based on the selection in a certain cell. Up until now I haven't had any issues with the code but I realized that every time I add rows to the Excel file, all the cell references are no longer correct. As a result, I'm trying to convert my code from cell references to named ranges and have reviewed some examples on this but I still can't seem to get it to work.

Can anyone please show me how to write the below code so that it uses Named Ranges instead of cell references?

```
If Target.Address(False, False) = "F43" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case 1: Rows("44").Hidden = False: Rows("45:50").Hidden = True
        Case 2: Rows("44:45").Hidden = False: Rows("46:50").Hidden = True
        Case 3: Rows("44:46").Hidden = False: Rows("47:50").Hidden = True
        Case 4: Rows("44:47").Hidden = False: Rows("48:50").Hidden = True
        Case 5: Rows("44:48").Hidden = False: Rows("49:50").Hidden = True
        Case 6: Rows("44:49").Hidden = False: Rows("50").Hidden = True
        Case "": Rows("44:50").Hidden = True
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: Use `Range("yourname").EntireRow` instead of `Rows(...)`?

Comment: Thank you! That worked for the Cases but what about the initial statement? `If Target.Address(False, False) = "F43" Then` what would I replace "F43" with

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("yournamedrange")) Is Nothing Then`.... use `Intersect` and avoid using `Address`.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!